# Login not working

Tags: android, authentication

I have written the simple code for Login authentication with hardcoded password.my problem is evenif I am entering the correct password my control is going in elese loop

```
edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);
s1=edt.getText().toString();

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d("mynameeeeee",s1);
      if(s1=="123")
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else
      {
         Log.d("coming in elseeeee","coming in elseeeee");
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not valid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem :

You are storing a reference of the edit text content at creation time, when the edit text is empty.

You should retrieve the content of the edit text EVERYTIME you want to compare, which is when the button is clicked in your case :

Do the following :

```java
edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);

btn.setOnClickListener ( new OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick ( View v ) {
            Log.d ( "mynameeeeee" , edt.getText().toString() );
            if ( edt.getText().toString().equals ( "123" ) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("coming in elseeeee","coming in elseeeee");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not valid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

the string should be compared like:

```
if(s1.equals("123")) {}
```

Comment: I believe you forgot one parenthesis after the equals statement.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if statement like this

```
if(s1.equals("123"))
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
       Log.d("coming in elseeeee","coming in elseeeee");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not valid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When comparing strings always use `.equals()` function

Answer (score 1):

`==` Checks whether both the variable are referring to same object. In this case since they are referring to different object so the result of `==` is false.

use equals() method `s1.equals("123")` to check the content of the string object.